# How to add dashes in an ID-number?

Tags: ada

**Beginner question!. I want to ask the user to write his/her birthday (ex: 19980231) and then print it out like this:1998-02-31. It may look simple to add dashes between numbers in Ada but I could not figure it out. Any suggestions?  Here is how far I have become**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;              use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

  procedure Dugga is
  N, M,Z,Y,X:Integer;
begin
Put("Write ur date of birth: ");
Get(X);
Y:= X/10000;
Put(Y); Put("-");
Z:= X - (Y*10000);
M:= Z/100;
if 9 < M then
Put(M,width=>0); Put("-");
elsif 9 >= M then
Put("0"); Put(M, width=>0);  Put("-");
end if;
Put(M,width=>0); Put("-");
N:= Z - (M*100);
Put(N, width=>0);
end Dugga;
```

Comment: Yeah we don't even know how you used Width or what you expected it to do or what it did different.

Comment: I have just updated my code. It kinda looks better but still do not know how to write it properly.

Comment: You're assuming `Integer` can hold an 8-digit number, That's very commonly true, but it's not guaranteed. (An alternative would be to read the information as a string.) This: `W:= X-X;` was probably a typo; it sets `W` to zero.

Comment: Yep. Now I used if statement to fix it and everything works fine :). It should be a better way to write this code and I wonder how?

Comment: Have you considered reading the input value as a string instead of an integer? There is no reason to convert from an integer to a string.

Answer (score 3):

The following program reads the input as a string, checking that the proper number of characters have been entered.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Birthday is
   Raw    : String (1 .. 8);
   Length : Natural := 0;
begin
   loop
      Put ("Enter a date in the format YYYYMMDD: ");
      Get_Line (Raw, Length);
      exit when Length = 8;
      Put_Line ("Wrong input format. Try again.");
   end loop;
   Put_Line (Raw (1 .. 4) & "-" & Raw (5 .. 6) & "-" & Raw (7 .. 8));
end Birthday;
```

Comment: This allows you to enter more than 8 characters.

Comment: Section A.10.7 of the LRM describes the Get_Line procedure as: "Reads successive characters from the specified input file and assigns them to successive characters of the specified string. Reading stops if the end of the string is met. Reading also stops if the end of the line is met before meeting the end of the string; in this case Skip_Line is (in effect) called with a spacing of 1. The values of characters not assigned are not specified." Therefore a maximum of 8 characters will be read from input.

Comment: True, but what if I e.g. double-typed one of the early characters? The code would "work" but give an incorrect answer, and there’d be an extra character left in the input buffer. It’d be safer to use the [functional form of `Get_Line`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html#p17.1)

Comment: If you use the functional form of Get_Line you will risk returning a string larger than the required 8 characters without fixing the problem of double-typing an early character. You would still have an incorrect answer. Unless the program requirements specify a correct range of year, month, and day values you cannot edit the input within the program.